# Compiler warnings with libgcrypt v1.5.0

Tags: c, libgcrypt

When I compile a sample program with `GCRYPT_NO_DEPRECATED` defined, I get the following 6 warnings:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libgcrypt/1.5.0/include/gcrypt.h:1336: warning: ‘gcry_ac_io_mode_t’ is deprecated
/usr/local/Cellar/libgcrypt/1.5.0/include/gcrypt.h:1337: warning: ‘gcry_ac_io_type_t’ is deprecated
/usr/local/Cellar/libgcrypt/1.5.0/include/gcrypt.h:1344: warning: ‘gcry_ac_data_read_cb_t’ is deprecated
/usr/local/Cellar/libgcrypt/1.5.0/include/gcrypt.h:1358: warning: ‘gcry_ac_data_write_cb_t’ is deprecated
/usr/local/Cellar/libgcrypt/1.5.0/include/gcrypt.h:1393: warning: ‘gcry_md_algo_t’ is deprecated
/usr/local/Cellar/libgcrypt/1.5.0/include/gcrypt.h:1401: warning: ‘gcry_md_algo_t’ is deprecated
```

Manually defining `_GCRYPT_IN_LIBGCRYPT` resolves the 6 warnings, but the manual is fairly strict in its exhortation:

> name prefixes with one prepended underscore are reserved for internal
>   use and should never be used by an application.

So how is one supposed to compile the gcrypt header without warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcrypt author says, "This is a bug in some compilers"

Suggested work around is

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
before the include, and
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
```

http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gcrypt-devel/2011-July/001829.html

http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gcrypt-devel/2011-July/001830.html